# Size Limit of List of messages sent using TopicClient/QueueClient.sendAsync(IList<Message>) in Microsoft Azure Service Bus - 2020

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am aware that the size for a single message using the SendAsync(Message) method is 1 MB, Confirming whether this also applies to the SendAsync(List) API also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single message limit is the limit of a batch (collection) of messages.
For the Standard tier, it's 256KB. For the Premium it's 1MB. The Premium tier will be launching a preview of 100MB message size support in the near future.

Comment: Shameless pug - if mixing the two and encountering message size issues with the standard, [ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/servicebus.attachmentplugin) can help. It can be conditionally registered based on the configuration/environment or conditionally executed by providing a [criteria at runtime](https://github.com/SeanFeldman/ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin#configure-criteria-for-message-max-size-identification).